# How to count number of active sessions in Java EE applications?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, listener, jaas

I am using JAAS for authentication in JBoss. I am using the DatabaseServerLoginModule to perform the authentication.

Now I want to track the number of active session in the application. I tried writing a HttpSessionListener but for some reason it is not getting called on successful login.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: " I tried writing a HttpSessionListener but for some reason it is not getting called on successful login." - This might mean that you have the session created even before a user is successfully authenticated. post your code

Comment: Unfortunately cant post my code. But it is pretty standard stuff. Not sure what you mean by "This might mean that you have the session created even before a user is successfully authenticated. post your code". Because I put a debug point in the listener and it is never getting called.

Comment: If it is never being called then it means the session is never being created (assuming u configured the session listener correctly).

Comment: @Pangea : interesting thought. I found online in some forums that session is not created until you explicitly call request.getSession. I tried doing that and viola my session listener gets called. But I was not able to find anything in the official documentation. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this thread https://community.jboss.org/message/415269. Seems like you have to explicitly manage the session. I am not sure how JAAS works. And more important how JAAS and HTTP Session lifecycle work together here: [JAAS and the HTTP Session Life Cycle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/session-lifecycle-096133.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It seems the session lister is not called until the you explicitly create a session using request.getSession(). The official documentation is strangely ambiguous. I added request.getSession() to my code and now the listener is correctly getting called.